# Decrypt JWE ECDH-ES+A256KW A256GCM

Tags: c#, jwe, ecdh

I'm trying to decrypt a JWE

```
eyJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwiYWxnIjoiRUNESC1FUytBMjU2S1ciLCJraWQiOiI3VGt5TWFqV0JYUlo3aVpmZ3lQUGZmMmdMMzloMlh0ZkpEemNzNXRjZXJNIiwiZXBrIjp7Imt0eSI6IkVDIiwiY3J2IjoiUC0yNTYiLCJ4IjoibXo1c3FfQi1YbFNYTW1oQm9YWDdmR0ZfME5wOFJqS3F0VUF3cXphU3dMZyIsInkiOiJJUVFRYzhpQVpMbzhiY2NfNUxEWW5kVEJIVXY0Rlc3T3loUHdwakZISmlJIn19.p81T3WizOuNm1XvU-PjksrrDvSExL93EBiC3tUYyJnpPSECXrCdAag.rxpe3T3vPcqenJpF.l29eduC5ZO4MzDsGzXoU-qqNHrWbdZbQulHM43-a0OxRl2NaqVJcyEP3v4JVmNFWZbSHp5IWS1lvM4Sr68l17qSq-voCKrUnqm-7HgEC2QP7pjP3waftgHTyvFYSoc3yXkTSvdL_5OUPcauW1Gay62d-iJWoJqO014VLoSicboMfiCc2bEn1J8iNeC4uWo2yuUgBjo-WR13xRTVi8-8kIjssrIB6aIJpTCdX7cghZ6O3SZZ0Cq8RWx0jcFy41fvxxko-8Z-d16MHqtnzGn4t12Hkjv9ux3KdiWUCy8w7nRvPyClS87pk5C_tqXyaT5vEa2t45JJk1mFbJIuco5C2idHCfDfYQUoBh-8cqvi-MAr9oncQMr5FrZtKmW5HBKCdK6FXZcDZrK0q6YFZXz0t-kc7-pJN6EGZLoRaVuQQ1GzQjpKmimvZ2eqOicBm8nJjT1ppd0NS-ypM_aaPbTtASeSvGQBwgLqxWAccZXbWXRPiqWTKkgRre6oumQtRabfPkdTAjNs7G4wosLDs4K4Qxse5lwvUubOVd4hPTZ8uzUJy3KbaUug3xtJ1ovYIEiA2cbJOhNapSqo3Xu3SKq1orw7eqO6ZfHrSEUb7B2io-ubgYYhTtPzRw3u_2jJVHfLbeszMKWEM291GDaz9_jyuaqGGtglJmeHQ2AUn-tjCVyQdn-txsTzT8gxK4QgK-3J7jnsrecXsiI9gLj1xcG4PTtmJXUtqz07-jaNok-w1H05XbVME3QaFk3tMeA0OYjNhOXpOzhL4AlDxQWwNQ-ulZKZHs1zPUlVDv0nlcpAsOfUqXlBJncAMJ1mvyHxvNMOZsTeLQav2aKr6S2c6uFknXOKAAI-E1x5WHB4SBs79MrWk8ipcMFrjmWhczQtFd2IYI2r820B_4VbBRsD7i-2D-oTO9JjRinxmvCrcT15z8yWP9b9GSbycsR3jkVXvjYKIaOHzcirq6TdufjPAp_ynyoSMg4EEWelRtzpTqzV253ZCK8HstIbHJm185TZh6hJdAQJpyVfKTjMH014U5jmbZTT3ik43WTD3VF_Uf_VWdXdBN-p5KboiNiC0VoTv8f0jAgU_dvYGNPuUJzytZXGYaTrkaSHqVgVLceqjFB8Q6OUTU7nVJ0d0S_vlEtioKGV6uAsLSSp8q_7B3DI1tZlVklAWfyw-GYpCBF09VU755ZcTiSe2wALp_P7-aAH14-2btknjrMAlQQrF9ZpDqzGT_vgQyDRTORrOdTN26AMCznr58ygmiSCfwFV0dmEKEI6dt7WNvVEuaFk8sKicUQlQFlQpX-YYFhaYGbulCZCuTUqDzQifi_D1VNqedGzfgbDclgVtDF7xLH6Sz7cwMIYsuWPttierh82QdFro0jDuNnbPZwU7TQBC2x8k8tn5nSH8SHd8yjR5uyQXtNTkLKaM_-NU_gJrX6Atalku3dIFUUKMB692vPw4Y154Eh8gYoYwgkwzZUJFgnjU3p2M139DFMMJyvTbiaPtKXx1Go_j8yEkgZpqG7nr7V_AisPCOQxu7Ewk3zi4_e3TQxhU3BcXMZCo8TApGpcoFa2lJIRpDK-KMHuyLnQK930OjdpvujhzDFynI7M36hA8msRVx3G2G2LNpDU4Hqd9FmVOwsmhZLdrcMUVxdB-l_bl9aYdHGjOMcAP_7A_VYX8fH5NlI9wTlPKiqwa23vdBuiaOjlZHjhDifK66s0TrOj7fQYmkAN4qn1AfjH5DTTa52U6z2g.8qcaLnQtJAdbUWAO8NiPMA
```

It has "header.encryptedKey.iv.ciphertext.tag" structure.
I've tried to use Jose-jwt NuGet package and it's working perfectly, but only on Windows, because it's using CngKey.Import which throws exception that Platform not supported.
I need to use it in Linux (Docker).

I've tried to use BountyCastle code snippets from ChatGPT, but it did not help me.
My last attempt was to use System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt 7.4.0. And yes, I'm using .NET 8.

My code:

```
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true;
IdentityModelEventSource.LogCompleteSecurityArtifact = true;

//header.encryptedKey.iv.ciphertext.tag
string encryptedToken = "myjwt";
string encryptionPrivateKey = File.ReadAllText("encryption_private_key.pem");
var ecdsa = ECDsa.Create(ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256);
ecdsa.ImportFromPem(encryptionPrivateKey);
var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
{
    TokenDecryptionKey = new ECDsaSecurityKey(ecdsa),
    ValidateIssuer = false, // установите значения в true, если нужна валидация этих параметров
    ValidateAudience = false,
    ValidateLifetime = false,
};

var jsonToken = handler.ReadToken(encryptedToken) as JwtSecurityToken;
var claims = handler.ValidateToken(encryptedToken, validationParameters, out var validatedToken);
Console.WriteLine(validatedToken);
```

Exception StackTrace:

```
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenKeyWrapException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=IDX10618: Key unwrap failed using decryption Keys: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.ECDsaSecurityKey, KeyId: '', InternalId: '7TkyMajWBXRZ7iZfgyPPff2gL39h2XtfJDzcs5tcerM'.
'.
Exceptions caught:
 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenKeyWrapException: IDX10659: UnwrapKey failed, exception from cryptographic operation: 'System.InvalidOperationException: IDX10665: Data is not authentic
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricKeyWrapProvider.UnwrapKeyPrivate(Byte[] inputBuffer, Int32 inputOffset, Int32 inputCount)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricKeyWrapProvider.UnwrapKey(Byte[] keyBytes)'
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricKeyWrapProvider.UnwrapKey(Byte[] keyBytes)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.GetContentEncryptionKeys(JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
'.
token: 'eyJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIiwiYWxnIjoiRUNESC1FUytBMjU2S1ciLCJraWQiOiI3VGt5TWFqV0JYUlo3aVpmZ3lQUGZmMmdMMzloMlh0ZkpEemNzNXRjZXJNIiwiZXBrIjp7Imt0eSI6IkVDIiwiY3J2IjoiUC0yNTYiLCJ4IjoibXo1c3FfQi1YbFNYTW1oQm9YWDdmR0ZfME5wOFJqS3F0VUF3cXphU3dMZyIsInkiOiJJUVFRYzhpQVpMbzhiY2NfNUxEWW5kVEJIVXY0Rlc3T3loUHdwakZISmlJIn19.p81T3WizOuNm1XvU-PjksrrDvSExL93EBiC3tUYyJnpPSECXrCdAag.rxpe3T3vPcqenJpF.l29eduC5ZO4MzDsGzXoU-qqNHrWbdZbQulHM43-a0OxRl2NaqVJcyEP3v4JVmNFWZbSHp5IWS1lvM4Sr68l17qSq-voCKrUnqm-7HgEC2QP7pjP3waftgHTyvFYSoc3yXkTSvdL_5OUPcauW1Gay62d-iJWoJqO014VLoSicboMfiCc2bEn1J8iNeC4uWo2yuUgBjo-WR13xRTVi8-8kIjssrIB6aIJpTCdX7cghZ6O3SZZ0Cq8RWx0jcFy41fvxxko-8Z-d16MHqtnzGn4t12Hkjv9ux3KdiWUCy8w7nRvPyClS87pk5C_tqXyaT5vEa2t45JJk1mFbJIuco5C2idHCfDfYQUoBh-8cqvi-MAr9oncQMr5FrZtKmW5HBKCdK6FXZcDZrK0q6YFZXz0t-kc7-pJN6EGZLoRaVuQQ1GzQjpKmimvZ2eqOicBm8nJjT1ppd0NS-ypM_aaPbTtASeSvGQBwgLqxWAccZXbWXRPiqWTKkgRre6oumQtRabfPkdTAjNs7G4wosLDs4K4Qxse5lwvUubOVd4hPTZ8uzUJy3KbaUug3xtJ1ovYIEiA2cbJOhNapSqo3Xu3SKq1orw7eqO6ZfHrSEUb7B2io-ubgYYhTtPzRw3u_2jJVHfLbeszMKWEM291GDaz9_jyuaqGGtglJmeHQ2AUn-tjCVyQdn-txsTzT8gxK4QgK-3J7jnsrecXsiI9gLj1xcG4PTtmJXUtqz07-jaNok-w1H05XbVME3QaFk3tMeA0OYjNhOXpOzhL4AlDxQWwNQ-ulZKZHs1zPUlVDv0nlcpAsOfUqXlBJncAMJ1mvyHxvNMOZsTeLQav2aKr6S2c6uFknXOKAAI-E1x5WHB4SBs79MrWk8ipcMFrjmWhczQtFd2IYI2r820B_4VbBRsD7i-2D-oTO9JjRinxmvCrcT15z8yWP9b9GSbycsR3jkVXvjYKIaOHzcirq6TdufjPAp_ynyoSMg4EEWelRtzpTqzV253ZCK8HstIbHJm185TZh6hJdAQJpyVfKTjMH014U5jmbZTT3ik43WTD3VF_Uf_VWdXdBN-p5KboiNiC0VoTv8f0jAgU_dvYGNPuUJzytZXGYaTrkaSHqVgVLceqjFB8Q6OUTU7nVJ0d0S_vlEtioKGV6uAsLSSp8q_7B3DI1tZlVklAWfyw-GYpCBF09VU755ZcTiSe2wALp_P7-aAH14-2btknjrMAlQQrF9ZpDqzGT_vgQyDRTORrOdTN26AMCznr58ygmiSCfwFV0dmEKEI6dt7WNvVEuaFk8sKicUQlQFlQpX-YYFhaYGbulCZCuTUqDzQifi_D1VNqedGzfgbDclgVtDF7xLH6Sz7cwMIYsuWPttierh82QdFro0jDuNnbPZwU7TQBC2x8k8tn5nSH8SHd8yjR5uyQXtNTkLKaM_-NU_gJrX6Atalku3dIFUUKMB692vPw4Y154Eh8gYoYwgkwzZUJFgnjU3p2M139DFMMJyvTbiaPtKXx1Go_j8yEkgZpqG7nr7V_AisPCOQxu7Ewk3zi4_e3TQxhU3BcXMZCo8TApGpcoFa2lJIRpDK-KMHuyLnQK930OjdpvujhzDFynI7M36hA8msRVx3G2G2LNpDU4Hqd9FmVOwsmhZLdrcMUVxdB-l_bl9aYdHGjOMcAP_7A_VYX8fH5NlI9wTlPKiqwa23vdBuiaOjlZHjhDifK66s0TrOj7fQYmkAN4qn1AfjH5DTTa52U6z2g.8qcaLnQtJAdbUWAO8NiPMA'.
  Source=System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt
  StackTrace:
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.GetContentEncryptionKeys(JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DecryptToken(JwtSecurityToken jwtToken, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateToken(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters, SecurityToken& validatedToken)
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\Vyacheslav\source\repos\ConsoleApp7\ConsoleApp7\Program.cs:line 23
```

My header of JWE:

```json
{
  "enc": "A256GCM",
  "alg": "ECDH-ES+A256KW",
  "kid": "7TkyMajWBXRZ7iZfgyPPff2gL39h2XtfJDzcs5tcerM",
  "epk": {
    "kty": "EC",
    "crv": "P-256",
    "x": "mz5sq_B-XlSXMmhBoXX7fGF_0Np8RjKqtUAwqzaSwLg",
    "y": "IQQQc8iAZLo8bcc_5LDYndTBHUv4FW7OyhPwpjFHJiI"
  }
}
```

Have you any ideas how to solve it?

Comment: Github issue created. I've a bit changed my code and new problem with Linux: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/issues/2518